# standalone excel from c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export

I export my html to excel like this :

```
// our html datas
// you can use foreach for repating
sTEXT = @"<table class='table'><thead>";
sTEXT += @"<th>";
sTEXT += @"Caption A";
sTEXT += @"</th>";
sTEXT += @"</thead>";
sTEXT += @"<tr>";
sTEXT += @"<td>abcdef</td>";
sTEXT += @"<td>ghjklm</td>";
sTEXT += @"</tr>";
sTEXT += @"</table>";

// our screen literaldata sets
lblData.Text = sTEXT;

// excel output code
// carefull end of the "Responce.Write"" sentence 
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
Response.Charset = "windows-1254";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedHtml.xls"); 
Response.Buffer = true;
this.EnableViewState = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Write("<style> TABLE { border: 1px solid gray; } TD { border: 1px solid gray; } </style> " + lblData.Text);
Response.End();
```

Everything looks fine in excel, there is no error.

But, when you save this exported excel file to another location (d:\, desktop...) Excel gets this error "missing file : ...html".
In that case I found this method is create some other directory and html files. Result : the excel file is not a standalone excel file.

So I want a standalone excel file. I need you suggestions ?

Comment: You need something that can write XLS/XLSX files, Excel can open/display HTML tables but despite the XLS extension, they are not excel files. Look up NPOI or EPPlus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)? 
I have used that in MVC application to convert MVC view into excel. 
Here's an example of such [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK)